# References for the Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

For understanding the [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations), are there any references which may include one or more of the followings:

- mathematical rigorousness
- motivation
- preliminaries
- introduction
- etc.

Comment: Well, concerning your first point, Galdi's "An introduction to the mathematical theory of the Navier-Stokes equations" could be a good start (if you're comfortable with the basics of real analysis). Temam's books (there are at least three I know of) are, I believe, a standard reference. Besides these most is in article form I believe, or in texts on fluid dynamics (maybe you could look into these for your other points).

Comment: In terms of motivation, and as mentioned by Jose27, any introductory text on fluid dynamics will suffice.

Comment: If you're looking for a very physical point of view, try Acheson's "Elementary Fluid Dynamics" (Oxford Univ. Press).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this is one of the Clay Institute of Mathematics Millennium Problems, I refer you to their [webpage](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/navier%E2%80%93stokes-equation) on the problem and to their [write-up](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/navierstokes.pdf) for the prize. It contains several references about the problem and some of the results on the problem. Their webpage also has a video lecture by Luis Caffarelli on the problem, which I think is really cool.

Answer (score 0):

This[1] is a great textbook on fundamentals of computational fluid dynamics, which includes a derivation of equations.

References:

[1] Hirsch, Charles. (2007). Numerical Computation of Internal and External Flows: The Fundamentals of Computational Fluid Dynamics. Elsevier